# using a dropdown in datatables can't get new values

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a drop-down that is inside a cell in my datatables i'm passing through the HTML to the datatables function. The problem is that when I click my save button the value that the drop-down loaded with is alerted however if i try changing the drop-down value the new value will not alerted the old value will.

for example if the first entry loads with Authorised then I change it to retired it will still print Authorised.

```
<select id="select" name="Status"> \
    <option value="Authorised">Authorised</option> \
    <option value="On Trial">On Trail</option> \
    <option value="Restricted-Use">Restricted-Use</option> \
    <option value="Retired">Retired</option> \
    <option value="Un-authorised">Un-authorised</option> \
</select>

<button id="SaveButt" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"  >Save</button>
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '#SaveButt', function () {



     alert($("#select").val());

});
```

I've tested this with just a static HTML example and it works fine. Also `$(document).on('change', '#SaveButt', function ()` doesnt work at all which leads me to believe that this is something to do with datatables.

If anyone can help.

[image]

[image: dd]

Comment: Assuming that `select` is repeated in every row then you need to use a `class` selector, not an `id`, otherwise you'll be duplicating them

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan currently i'm just testing the first row as i can't get it to work, in reality the id is "select'+counter2+' " and the first option is also variable that is not there.

Comment: Exactly what you want? Can you explain so that I can help you out!

Comment: @ForamTrada so if i click the dropdown and change the dropdown from authorised to On Trial and then i click the save button it will alert On Trial, currently it will still alert authorised.

Comment: Can you show records in datatable in image/screenshot, so that we can visualize what your page looks like.

Comment: @ishpreet added the images

Comment: @adamWadsworth - Your save button is at the end of datatable? In datatable, there are more than one records? In image, you are showing just one record, and in actual, whether there can be more than one records?

Comment: @Ishpreet yes the save button is down the bottom of the page it's not really relevant as it works fine it just a way of triggering the code. The table has multiple rows. but because i can't get the currently selected value i'm just testing with the first value as it's easier to test. originally the code adds all the values in the column to an array and again this works but it doesn't change the value when i change the value in the dropdown

Comment: @adamWadsworth - Ok, do one thing, first of all, change `id` to `class` for `select` input as you have multiple records, `id` will not work. Try with `class` . If still not works, let me know.

Comment: @Ishpreet  currently i'm just testing the first row as i can't get it to work, in reality the id was "select'+counter2' " and the first option is also variable that is not there This has the same issue

Comment: @ishpreet https://jsfiddle.net/xgv4at9y/2/ this is how it should be working

Comment: @adamWadsworth - The jsfiddle link you have shared was not working because you have not loaded jquery library, jsfiddle is purely javascript based. Now, I have attached jquery file and it is perfectly working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jsfiddle link: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxveqL67/).
Here, multiple rows are showing and on click of `Savebutt`, each dropdown correct value is displaying. This link may help you or may give some direction.
If you still faces problem in your code, then there may be other problem is persisting like script files are interfering with each other or may be some hidden variable is existing which is showing you value. You have to check your view source code and should find whether some hidden value of same id is existing or not or you can share view source code of datatable part only in image form.

Comment: I've said in my question that it works fine if you just write static HTML and then add the select. I think the problem comes from datatables.js

Comment: @adamWadsworthL I have mentioned in my answer that if not working in your case, then it may be issue of script files interfering with each other or may be something else. We can help you if we can see `view source code` of your page.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like this.

```js
$('#SaveButt').click(function(){
     alert($("#select").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select" name="Status"> \
    <option value="Authorised">Authorised</option> \
    <option value="On Trial">On Trail</option> \
    <option value="Restricted-Use">Restricted-Use</option> \
    <option value="Retired">Retired</option> \
    <option value="Un-authorised">Un-authorised</option> \
</select>

<button id="SaveButt" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Save</button>
```

Comment: this makes no difference it's just a different way of activating the click function

Comment: I know i've said in my question that it works fine if you just write static HTML and then add the select. I think the problem comes from datatables.js